# Can I cook a thawed turkey?

Tags: food-safety

I bought a PC stuffed turkey roll. It said keep frozen but I accidently left it in the fridge for two days. Is it still safe to cook from its defrosted state? It is small and stuffed.

Comment: If it's been in the refrigerator for just two days, then it's only just thawed out, but you should cook it now as soon as possible. Did it give you an oven temperature and time for the frozen product?

Answer (score 2):

Check the cooking instructions - if it says to cook from frozen, and doesn't mention defrosting as an option, it probably isn't safe. Some foods are meant to be placed in the oven frozen, and defrosting them increases the risk of stomach upset because of various bacteria levels. If, on the other hand, it gives defrosting instructions as well as, or instead of, saying cook from frozen, it should be okay.